# Getting ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB with Database First in .net

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

So I am using EF database first on an oracle db. I am getting the above error when I do this in my code:

```
contractType.CLIENT_TYPE != null && contractType.CLIENT_TYPE.ToUpper() == "POL"
```

That column is defined as VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) in Oracle and the .net type is string.

Did a lot of searching and no one really mentions this error in the context of .net. Hoping someone might have an idea.

Comment: Seems like you are filtering out a CLOB column without casting it as VARCHAR2. Can you describe your table.

Comment: It's a 10 column table. Nothing fancy honestly. I've been using EF database first against this database already with no issues. But for some reason when I try to check if Client_Type == "POL" it blows up.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out a solution to this. I was using Odp.net version 11. Apparently this is a bug with certain linq statements using the where extension method. I upgraded to odp.net version 12 and it fixed the issue.